# Register service prefix in plugin - ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

Is there a way to add a prefix for all routes belonging to the same services inside of the plugin?

I have several services. Each one of them stays in a separate class (eg UserService.cs..). The services are grouped in category, and each categories is represented by a project.

So, first: instead of registering each service in the AppHost and then in the *Service.cs by specifying the "[Route("/somewhere"]" can i register the services only once in the plugin?

But here it comes the real question: even if the answer to the first question would be "No", can I specify a route prefix in the plugin that every service belonging to it, will inherit?
This way:

I want the service to be at /admin/user and i would like to do it that way:

Plugin side:

```
    appHost.RegisterService<UserService>("/admin");
```

and on the serviceside i would like to use:

```
    [Route("/user")]
    public class UserService: Service
```

Can I implement it somehow?
Thanks

Comment: Exactly my question, some 5 years later =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Routes are defined per-operation and are not contextually-sensitive on any hidden configuration, and do not cascade - what you see is what you can expect.

The [Auto Route generation strategies](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#auto-route-generation-strategies) allows you to infer and customize auto-routing conventions. See the implementation of [RouteNamingConvention](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/RouteNamingConvention.cs) for examples on how you can provide your own route generation strategies.

Answer (score 1):

Now, 5 years later, I want to just let ppl know how I "solved it". I think this is an ugly way to solve it, more like a hack, as I could not get it to work any other way.

The only way I could do it was to override GetRouteAttributes and hardcode it, like below. As you can see, I am looking on the string representation and hardcoding it if I find a match. This seems to solve what @PizzaBoy asked and also what I was looking for.

```c#
namespace tWorks.Alfa.Modules.ModuleRestApiService
{
    public class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("HttpListener Self-Host", typeof(Services.AlfaProService.AlfaProService).Assembly)
        {
        }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container) { }

        public override RouteAttribute[] GetRouteAttributes(Type requestType)
        {
            var routes = base.GetRouteAttributes(requestType);
            if (requestType.FullName.Contains(nameof(Services.AlfaConnectService.AlfaConnectService)))
            {
                routes.Each(x => x.Path = "/alfaconnect" + x.Path);
            }
            else if (requestType.FullName.Contains(nameof(Services.AlfaProService.AlfaProService)))
            {
                routes.Each(x => x.Path = "/alfapro" + x.Path);
            }
            return routes;            
        }
    }
}
```

My structure looks like this:

[image]